# Dismiss ViewController by pull down TableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I had checked many cocoa pods many of them giving functionality only for view controller dismissal, found some that using dismissal of view controller that contain table view in full screen but they are doing for swift and when I translate to swift to objective c found Tableview does not take touches. I want this animation for iOS 10 to onward. I knew it, iOS 13 Apple already providing this animation for a modally presenting view controller. [image: Sample]

Comment: There are a number of steps you must take to achieve this and a few different ways to get there. The way I recommend is to first create the custom present/dismiss animations, then make the dismiss interactive using an interactive controller like `UIPercentDrivenInteractiveTransition`, and then using the table's pan gesture recognizer to drive the dismiss using the interactive controller. It's a quite a bit of work if you've never done it before but the steps are all very straightforward.

Comment: You might be able to implement this by creating your own presentation controller, and wiring up your scroll view to send events to the presentation controller to trigger a `transition`once dragged below a certain point. It's quite a bit of work however.

Comment: Thanks @bsod I was thinking people’s already created pods for it

Comment: No need for a pod, it’s just a couple of components.

Comment: @bsod issues comes when pan gesture blocked tableview touches

Comment: Don't add a pan gesture recognizer, use the one in the table view. `UITableView` is a subclass of `UIScrollView` and from `scrollViewDidScroll`, you can access the pan gesture recognizer. Use that to drive the dismiss.